# Are arrays allowed in the socket.io emit function?

Tags: arrays, socket.io

Is it possible to send arrays of objects in the `socket.io` emit function?

For example,

```
io.emit("message", [{data: 123},{data: 456}]);
```

Comment: Try it, and find out.  Have you attempted to do so?  If you run into errors or it doesn't work as you anticipated, it might lead you to a more specific question.  For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is.

You can send almost any type, and can nest any type within another type:

- Strings `""`
- Numbers `123`
- Arrays `[]`
- Objects `{}`
- Booleans `true/false`
- Undefined `undefined`
- Null `null`
- Blobs `Blob()`
- Files `File()`
- Combinations `[{"example:123},{bool:true},[1,2,undefined],blob]`

And others. Hope that helps!